# Assign a new column in pandas in a similar way as in pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 1],['B', 2],['C', 3]], columns=['index', 'result'])
```

| index | result |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |

I would like to create a new column, for example multiply the column 'result' by two, and I am just curious to know if there is a **way to do it in pandas** as pyspark does it.

```
In pyspark:
df = df\
.withColumn("result_multiplied", F.col("result")*2)
```

I don't like the fact of writing the name of the dataframe everytime I have to perform an operation as it is done in pandas such as:

```
In pandas:
df['result_multiplied'] = df['result']*2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df = df.assign(result_multiplied = df['result']*2)
```

Or if column `result` is processing in code before is necessary lambda function for processing counted values in column `result`:

```
df = df.assign(result_multiplied = lambda x: x['result']*2)
```

Sample for see difference column `result_multiplied` is count by multiple original `df['result']`, for `result_multiplied1` is used multiplied column after `mul(2)`:

```
df = df.mul(2).assign(result_multiplied = df['result']*2,
                      result_multiplied1 = lambda x: x['result']*2)
print (df)
  index  result  result_multiplied  result_multiplied1
0    AA       2                  2                   4
1    BB       4                  4                   8
2    CC       6                  6                  12
```